# How are 'them' and 'werewolves' placed together?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> Should’ve thought of **them werewolves** before you got
>   in trouble, shouldn’t you?

This is a sentence from *Harry Potter I*.  Would it not be appropriate to omit **them** from the sentence?

Comment: It's a local dialect expression using "them" for "those." Omitting it would change the meaning. But it ain't standard.

Comment: What makes the sentence sound odd is that most of it is in standard English, and only the phrase "them werewolves" is in dialect.  If the entire sentence had been translated into dialect, it would have left a lot of readers baffled.  For one thing, I am pretty sure "before you" would have become "afor ye".

Comment: Gosh. That's the first inconsistency I've ever encountered in the whole series...

Comment: Not really an inconsistency. Plenty of people speak parts of a dialect, especially if they spend time in two cultures, or are transitioning from one to another.

Comment: Note that it's not always just "dialect".  It would be perfectly proper to say "Should’ve thought of them before you got in trouble".  The speaker may start to say this but, while speaking, insert "werewolves" to make the statement clearer, resulting in that construction.